Unable to save appscript.json for custom menu addon
I am having an error when saving appscript.json (appscript.json has invalid unsaved changes). I am trying to build a custom menu and deploy as a test add-on in my google workspace (so that other users may use it). The custom menu script functions works on its own.
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Singapore",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
  "AddOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Custom Menu Tools",
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "enabled": true,
        "runFunction": "onOpen"
      }
    },
    "docs": {
    }
   }  
}



There should be a comma after V8

With Google Apps Scripts, you can create two types of add-ons: Workspace Add-ons and Editor Add-ons.
It might be possible that you are confused about the capabilities of each type of add-on. You should make an Editor add-on to add a custom menu that is created using an onOpen trigger. You don't need to edit the Apps Script project manifest for this type of add-on.
Below is the minimal code to make an add-on for Google Docs that adds a custom menu.
function onInstall(e){
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e){

  const menu = DocumentApp.getUi().createAddOnMenu();

  menu.addItem('First Item', 'doSomething')
      .addToUi();
}

function doSomething(){
  // Add here something to do
}

To make it easier to test/debug and

Create a new document, click on Extensions > Apps Script.
Change the project's default name to a descriptive name.
On the Code.gs file, replace the boilerplate code with the above code. Click Save.
This will automatically update the Apps Script project manifest.

A basic test is to run onOpen. The first time, you will be required to authorize the script, authorize it, and then open the tab of the Google Document. This should show you the custom menu.
Another test is to close and reopen the document. The custom menu should be shown.
A third test is to create a test deployment. For details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments.

Specifics about Google Workspace Addon
From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/homepage-trigger



Fields






enabled
boolean
Whether or not homepage (non-contextual) cards are enabled for this host application. Defaults to true.


runFunction
string
The name of the function to run this trigger fires. If specified, you must implement this function to build and return an array of one or more Card objects for display as this add-on's homepage in this host application.




Resources

Add-ons types
Custom Menus in Google Workspace

Related

Google App Script Add-Ons createAddonMenu() create a Help menu. How to call it?
Menu item doesn't appear after publishing google addon
Add-on menu not showing up in new documents
Using Google Apps Script code to create a custom menu in Google Sheets

